# Access items from within a list of objects

Tags: python, django

I am trying to retrieve all of the userstories from a list of sprints which have a particular group that the user logged in is a part of.

I have been able to get all of the sprints using a for loop:

```
{% for sprint in user.groups.all.0.sprints.all %}
```

I want to be able to get the items from within each sprint that I have retrieved using the above loop. How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the relevant models? I expect you would just loop over `{% for item in sprint.items.all %}` or similar

Comment: I had forgotten to add ```.all``` at the end of the loop. This has worked. Thank you!